# Resources file missing after dotnet restore of nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I've made a nuget package containing a generated `xml` documentation file and published this package on a private repository.

Here is the `.csproj` of the nuget package.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <DocumentationFile>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Test.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Test.xml">
        <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

When I restore this packages on other machines using `dotnet restore Another.Project.csproj`, the package is restored correctly but the `xml` documentation file is missing.

I can see that the file `lib/netcoreapp2.2/Test.xml` exists inside `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\test\1.x.x\Test.1.x.x.nupkg`.

But for some reasons it's not extracted to the `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\test\1.x.x\lib\netcoreapp2.2\` directory.

#### How can I make sure the `xml` resource file get extracted when I restore the package?

---

#### Notes

- I need to do this since I'm following this blog post to use the `xml` file in swagger https://snede.net/add-nuget-package-xml-documentation-to-swagger/
- I'd like to avoid setting the `xml` file build action to `Content` if possible.
- The `dll` files are extracted correctly. The package is working as intended.

Comment: I was searching for the solution for the above question. @Justin Lessard - did you find any solution for this? Here is the question I asked but the command is being executed by team city - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63747258/nuget-restore-is-ignoring-xml-files-but-downloading-only-dll-and-pdb-files?noredirect=1#comment112774651_63747258