# Nuget restore is ignoring .xml files but downloading only .dll and .pdb files

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, proget

The nuget package Project Xyz contains all xml files along with dll and pdb files. We are using this package Xyz in a different project Abc of a different solution.

We have a team city build setup for publishing the package Xyz to Proget feed(we use proget for private nuget packages repository).

We also have a Team City build setup to compile and deploy the Abc project. But, while compiling the build, when we restore the nuget package, it downloads only dll/pdb files but not xml files. In  the build step of team city, we have runner type as dotnet and command as restore.

How do we make it restore xml files as well?

This is a follow up question to the above link? We followed below link to publish nuget package with xml files.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353505/5887074

Please note: Even though project level environment variables in team city has NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=none, dot net restore is overriding environment variable for some reason with [Environment] NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE = skip

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT - any idea about this?

Comment: Maybe you could try to push your new nuget package into teamcity nuget server. See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/nuget-publish.html).

Comment: We did publish the package to proget feed where we are able to see all xml along with pdb/dll files. But while restoring, it only restores pdb and dll files and ignores xml files. Added more description in the question as well.

Comment: Have you tried adding the ```--verbosity detailed``` argument to the restore step? May give some insight into why the xml is being excluded.

Comment: Yes we tried that and found this. Even though project level environment variables in team city has NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=none, dot net restore is overriding environment variable for some reason with [Environment] NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE = skip

Comment: Hey Vicky, while packaging it included all XML's and PDB and dll's. Can you tell me how it's restoring dll and pdb for you, I have only dll restored.